# What GPU computing can do?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I almost know nothing about GPU computing. I already have seen articles written about GPU computing, say [Fast minimum spanning tree for large graphs on the GPU](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1572769.1572796&coll=ACM&dl=ACM&type=series&idx=SERIES304&part=series&WantType=Proceedings&title=GH) or [All-pairs shortest-paths for large graphs on the GPU](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1413966). It sounds GPU has some restrictions in computing that CPU doesn't have. I need to know what kind of computations a GPU can do?

thanks.

Comment: It can do anything, but the hardware is better suited for massively parallel tasks. Anyways, this question doesn't really belong on this site.

Comment: @NeilLocketz A parallel algorithm for Minimum Spanning Tree has already been presented, what is difference between parallel cpu and gpu?

Comment: GPU is *much* more parallel than a normal multi-core CPU. The high end of the nVidia 10XX series has around 4,000 cores. The cores operate at a lower clock rate than CPU cores, so each task is slower, but they do all those things at once, so throughput can be faster for parallel tasks.

Comment: Related: [Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (as they used to say in my school, "Tell about this to all these PHP folks who learned how to program in the internet...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm a CUDA rookie with some experience, so I think I may help with a response from one begneer to another one.

A very short answer to your question is:

**It can do the very same thing as CPU, but it has different features which can make it deliver the desired result faster or slower (if you take in account the same cost in hardware).**

The CPU, even multicore ones seeks lower latency and it leads to set of demands in construction. On the opposite direction, GPU assumes that you have so much independent data to process in a way that if you process a single instruction for each data entry result from the first data entry should be available to take part in the next code instruction before processing everything in the current instruction (it is kinda hard to achieve and a expressive amount of experience in parallel development is required). Thus, the GPU construction does not take in account the processing latency with the same intensity as CPU does, because it can be "hidden" by the bulk processing, also, it does not worry that much about the clock frequency, since it can be compensated in the number of processors.

So, I would not dare to say that GPU has restrictions over CPU, I would say that it has a more specific processing purpose, as a sound card for example, and it construction takes advantage of this specificity. Comparing both is the same as comparing a snowmobile to a bike, it does not make real sense.

**But, one thing, is possible to state: if a high parallel approach is possible, the GPU can provide more efficiency for a lower cost than CPU**, just remember that CPU stands for Central Processing Unit, and Central can be understood as it must be more general the peripheric ones.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code should consists of so many loops so that scheduler can switch between loops when it can't find enough resources to complete a loop. After that you should make sure that your code doesn't face one of the following lamitaions:

1.Divergance: If your code has long `if statements` then your code is likely to be divergant on GPU. Every 32 threads are grouped together and one instruction is assigned to all of them at once. So when the `if` is excuted on some threads, others that fall into `else statement` should wait and vice versa, which drops performance.

2. Uncoalesced memory access: One other thing is memory access pattern. If you access global memory orderly then you can utilize maximum memory bandwidth but if your access to data on global memory is misordered then you'll find memory access as a botteleneck. So if your code is very cache favorable, don't go for GPU as the ratio of ALU/cache on GPU is mich lower than CPU.
3. Low occupancy: If your code consume so many registers, shared memory, loading/ storing data and especial math functions (like trigonometrics) then it's likely that you find shortage in resources which prevent you to establish the full computational capacity of GPU.